Inquiry Regarding Google Calendar API Settings for Retrieving 'Public Holidays Only' Japanese calendar
I am looking for a Java calendar ID for Google Calendar API that returns only public holidays.
Japanese Google Calendar settings

Holiday Calendar content (Japanese Settings)

"祝日およびその他の休日"：japanese__ja@holiday.calendar.google.com
"祝日のみ"：？

need the calendar ID the arrow is pointing to






I understand that what you need is a calendar ID is this correct? I just want to confirm if you want a third party calendar ID that you can use, something that was created by another person the same one pre created by Google? If this is the case I do think what you need is create a new calendar and include the Japanese Public holiday if this is not what you want can you confirm how it was different?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Calendar Setting and What is included on Calendar ID
Calendar ID is an Unique Identifier for an Entity. Depending on the Setting which is shown on your calendar it will reflect the same thing. I understand that you want to be more specific on what's included as well. On this link Calendar Settings I was able to change the settings about holiday on my solutions created from the past.
Sample Settings:

Reference:
Add or Remove Holiday
Note: Feel free to use what I have shared to accomplish your goal with Google Calendar API, please feel free to add more information with your post this way the community can also share, what is implementation to get the information you are trying to get from Calendar API
